# Проблема с вебдрайвером

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

не запускается драйвер, понять в чем дело не могу, без аргумента в webdriver.Chrome() все норм

```
`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import time

chrome_driver_path = Service('/home/alex/PycharmProjects/selenium_learn/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver1')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_driver_path)
link = 'https://www.google.com'
try:
    driver.get(url=link)
    time.sleep(5)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

`

ощибка

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/selenium_learn/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    driver.close()
  File "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/selenium_learn/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 551, in close
    self.execute(Command.CLOSE)
  File "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/selenium_learn/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/selenium_learn/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer)
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.119)```
````

Comment: пробовал и через webdriver_manager.chrome - ничего не выходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо проверить, соответствует ли версия вебдрайвера версии хрома.
Также проблема может быть в измененном файле host - начинаться он должен со строки 127.0.0.1  localhost

Comment: версии совпадают, host в норме